# Como resolver problema compilador C++ Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilação, mingw

Estava tentando fazer um Hello World em C++ no Visual Studio, porém ao tentar compilar e rodar o programa não era exibido nenhum bug, apenas uma mensagem de erro do compilador C/C++.

Já instalei o MingGW, e as extensões C/C++ IntelliSense e Compiler. Também tentei adicionar o `#include "stdafx.h"` antes do `#include <iostream>`e ainda assim não funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: Também não estou conseguindo compilar e rodar o codígo em nenhuma outra IDE, Notepad++, CodeBlocks, DevC++.

Desculpa se a pergunta não ficou boa, ou se ficou faltando alguma informação, é a primeira vez que estou usando o Stack Overflow para um problema pessoal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No instalador do MingGW, lá em "basic setup" , você tem certeza que marcou as caixinhas "mingw32-base-bin e mingw32-gcc-g++-bin"? Depois de instaladas, você deve adicionar a pasta \MingGW\Bin nas variáveis do sistema, conforme fotos a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]